# Pre-configure server connection with Visual Studio Team Explorer 2013

Tags: tfs, team-explorer

We have packaged VS Team Explorer 2013 build for our enterprise non-Visual Studio users. Once the package is pushed to remote users' workstations, they have to enter our internal TFS server name in the Servers list while establishing connection. Though it's one time configuration but I'm looking to make a seamless experience for our TFS users by pre-configuring the server details and connection settings. So as a new user I can see my TeamExplorer already connected to my in-house enterprise TFS servers.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@Sam, you're correct that Visual Studio stores TFS connection URLs in Registry(HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\TeamFoundation\Instances), and you need to take this approach.

Additionally, you can also store login user accounts in the Windows Credential Manager to avoid adding user accounts when connect to TFS in VS.